# Python - Share global variables across modules from user-defined config file

Tags: python, configuration

## Goal

My program takes a yaml config file as parameter `python myprogram.py cfg.yml`.

- all modules can access the cfg content with a simple module import
- the imported `config` behaves like the loaded top-level yaml dictionary for reading operations

```
# module_a.py
from config_module import cfg_class as config
print(config['pi'])
```

## Reasoning

I wanted to follow the official python FAQ to [share config global variables across modules](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules) but I could only define the parameters in a pre-defined file that cannot be changed by the user:

```
# config_module.py
pi = 3.14
```

To let the user choose a yaml config file, I changed config.py to:

```
# config_module.py
class cfg_class:
    pass
```

and the very top of `myprogram.py` to

```
# myprogram.py
from config_module import cfg_class as config
import yaml
if __name__=='__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        cfg_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)
    config.cfg_dict = cfg_dict
```

As a result all modules have access to the config content

```
# module_a.py
from config_module import cfg_class as config
print(config.cfg_dict['pi'])
```

Instead of using `config.cfg_dict['pi']` I wanted to use `config['pi']`. To do that I defined the `__getitem__` for the `cfg_class`:

```
class cfg_class:
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return self.cfg_dict[x]
```

It failed with `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. An explanation to this problem is [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12447078). It indicates that we need a metaclass for cfg_class:

```
# config.py
class Meta(type):
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return cfg_class.cfg_dict[x]

class cfg_class(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

And now it works. Below is the code for

```
config_module.py
myprogram.py
module_a.py
module_b.py
cfg.yml
```

Any feedback?

## Working code

```
# config_module.py
class Meta(type):
    def __getitem__(self, x):
        return cfg_class.cfg_dict[x]

class cfg_class(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

```
# myprogram.py
import sys
import yaml

from config_module import cfg_class as config
import module_a
import module_b

if __name__=='__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        cfg_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)
    config.cfg_dict = cfg_dict

    module_a.a_class_from_module_a()
    module_b.a_class_from_module_b()
```

```
# module_a.py
from config_module import cfg_class as config

class a_class_from_module_a:
    def __init__(self):
        print(
            'I am an instance of a_class_from_module_a'
            ' and I have access to config: ',
            config['pi']
        )
```

```
# module_b.py
from config_module import cfg_class as config

class a_class_from_module_b:
    def __init__(self):
        print(
            'I am an instance of a_class_from_module_b'
            ' and I have access to config: ',
            config['pi']
        )
```

```
# cfg.yml
---
pi: 3.14
...
```

Result:

```
$ python myprogram.py cfg.yml
>> I am an instance of a_class_from_module_a and I have access to config:  3.14
>> I am an instance of a_class_from_module_b and I have access to config:  3.14
```

#### Edit: simpler solution thanks to @MiguelAlorda who almost got it all right and @RootTwo who fixed the problem

```
# config_module.py
import yaml

config = {}

def load_config(file_str: str) -> None:
    global config
    with open(file_str) as f:
        # config = yaml.safe_load(f) # does not work because it unbinds config, see comment from @RootTwo
        config.update(yaml.safe_load(f))
```

```
# myprogram.py
import sys
import config_module
import module_a
import module_b

if __name__=='__main__':
    config_module.load_config(sys.argv[1])
    
    x = module_a.a_class_from_module_a()
    y = module_b.a_class_from_module_b()
    print(x,y)
```

```
# module_a.py
from config_module import config

class a_class_from_module_a:
    def __init__(self):
        print(
            'I am an instance of a_class_from_module_a'
            ' and I have access to config: ',
            config['pi']
        )
```

```
# module_b.py
from config_module import config

class a_class_from_module_b:
    def __init__(self):
        print(
            'I am an instance of a_class_from_module_b'
            ' and I have access to config: ',
            config['pi']
        )
```

```
#cfg.yml
---
pi: 3.14
...
```

Output:

```
$ python myprogram.py cfg.yml
I am an instance of a_class_from_module_a and I have access to config:  3.14
I am an instance of a_class_from_module_b and I have access to config:  3.14
<module_a.a_class_from_module_a object at 0x000002391D5F8F48> <module_b.a_class_from_module_b object at 0x000002391D5FB288>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to Code Review!

I think this approach is a bit overkill. You could simply have a `config` dict in the `config_module`, and have a `config_module.load_config(file_str: str) -> None` function:

```py
# config_module.py
import yaml

config = {}

def load_config(file_str: str) -> None:
    global config
    with open(file_str) as f:
        config.update(yaml.safe_load(f))
```

And then in you main:

```py
import sys

import config_module

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config_module.load_config(sys.argv[1])
```

Using the config:

```py
from config_module import config

config["some_config_key"]
```